# Undefined Variable Inside Controller ($scope issue)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, callback, scope

All, I have the following AngularJS below. Why is `$scope.gotData` not visible outside of the call to `getData.success()`? Note that `$scope.gotData` is visible to the view: I can display the value of `scope.gotData` by placing `{{gotData}}` within my `index.html`.

Why can I not access `$scope.gotData` as a variable elsewhere in my controller? This is a question concerning the details of $scope.

#### getData.js

```
myApp.factory('getData',function($http){
return $http.jsonp('https://foo.com/bar.json')
       .success(function(data){
            return data;
        })
        .error(function(err){
            return err;
        });
});
```

#### MainController.js

```
myApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope','getData', function($scope, getData){
    getData.success(function(data){
        $scope.gotData = data;
    });

    $scope.gotData /* NOT DEFINED HERE */
   }]);
```

#### index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="js/vendor/angular.js"></src>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
      {{gotData}} /* I CAN SEE THE DATA HERE */
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason **why you cannot see `$scope.gotData` outside the `getData.success()`** function is because `.success()` is ***async*** and the value is not available when you try to access it outside `.success()`. This essentially means that the promise has not been resolved yet.

Moreover, once angular's digest cycle identifies that `$scope.gotData` is populated, it quickly updates the view. Thats the reason **why you can see `$scope.gotData` in the view**

Things would be more clear once you put a `watch` on `$scope.gotData`

```
 myApp.controller('MainController', ['$watch','$scope','getData', function($watch,$scope, getData){
     getData.success(function(data){
        $scope.gotData = data;
     });

    $scope.$watch($scope.gotData,function(n,o){
       console.log("new val-> "+n);
       console.log("old val->"+o);
     })   
 }]);
```

Comment: So, the promise is only resolved when ``getData.success`` is called from the controller? I want to understand the "digest cycle" and these "promises" ($q). Do you have a good layman's resource for understanding what Angular is doing in the background?

Comment: Well, yea. When the promise is resolved, `.success` is called, and when it is rejected, `.error` is called. You can get a better idea on promises from this [link](http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html). Also, [this](http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angularjs-corner-using-promises-q-handle-asynchronous-calls/) and [this](https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/promises) are nice places to get started with `$q`. Here's the [official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) on $q

Comment: I'll read those. I had already found the official documentation but the Angular API can be pretty opaque if you don't have a background in computer science. I'm reading on the ``$watch`` service right now. [This site](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/08/watch-how-the-apply-runs-a-digest/) is pretty good.

Answer (score 4):

the call to getData.success is asynchronous. So before executing that success function, your call to console of $scope.gotData is done. So you are supposed to define a default value of this $scope.gotData beforehand. And when you get a success call, only then you should use it. Something like this :

```
myApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope','getData', function($scope,getData){

    $scope.gotData = null;

    getData.success(function(data){
        $scope.gotData = data;
    });

    if($scope.gotData != null) 
        // Do something useful with this data
}]);
```

Comment: So, does this mean that once the data has been retrieved that ``$scope.gotData`` is then defined? If the server responds fairly quickly then I should be able to ``setTimeout(console.log($scope.gotData),1000)`` outside of the call to ``getData.success`` to see the data, right?

Comment: Yes..You'd be able to see the data if you use setTimeout(or `$timeout` service if you want to do thing more angular way).
*Provided* you get the data within 1 second(1000 milliseconds)

Answer (score 0):

Although not the best programming practice, but a solution to this is to use $rootScope.

```js
myApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope','getData', function($scope, getData){
    getData.success(function(data){
        $rootScope.gotData = data;
    });

    console.log($rootScope.gotData) // this will be accessible across
                                    // different controllers aswell
   }]);
```

Comment: Thanks, Asad. I'm going to avoid using $rootScope. That's playing with fire.