# $scope variable is undefined when it is set inside a function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have the following example code in my learning app. The service does his job and pulls some data out of a page with json code generated by php, so far so good.

**service:**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.data')
        .service('DashboardService', DashboardService);

    DashboardService.$inject = ['$http'];
    function DashboardService($http) {

        this.getFormules = getFormules;

        ////////////////

        function getFormules(onReady, onError) {
            var formJson = 'server/php/get-formules.php',
                formURL  = formJson + '?v=' + (new Date().getTime()); // Disables cash

            onError = onError || function() { alert('Failure loading menu'); };

            $http
                .get(formURL)
                .then(onReady, onError);
        }

    }
})();
```

Then i call the getFormules function in my controller and put all the data inside my $scope.formuleItems and test if everything succeeded and 'o no'... `$scope.formuleItems = undefined!` - *Strange because my view is showing data?*

**part of the controller:**

```
    dataLoader.getFormules(function (items){

        $scope.formuleItems = items.data;

    });

    console.log('+++++++++++++++++', $scope.formuleItems); // gives undefined
```

The first thing i did was search around on stackoverflow to look if someone else had the same issue, and there was: [Undefined variable inside controller function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31371331/undefined-variable-inside-controller-scope-issue).

I know there are some walkarounds for this, i've done my own research, but something tells me that this (see example below) isn't the best way to solve this problem.

*solution one: put $watch inside of the controller*

```
$scope.$watch('formuleItems', function(checkValue) {
   if (checkValue !== undefined) {
     //put the code in here!
  }
}
```

or even:

```
if($scope.formuleItems != null) {}
```

The rest of the controller is relying on $scope.formuleItems. Do i really have to put everything into that `$watch` or `if`? Can i fix this with a promise? I never did that before so some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Javascript is run asynchronous. How do you know that your function that sets that value is running before your log to the console? There's a good question that covers that but I can't find it currently. However that's what you need to read up on. Found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: I suggest you read http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/, which describes, among others, the two traps about angular promises that you fell into: not understanding asynchronism, and passing callback functions instead of not passing anything and returning a promise.

Comment: Wow, JB Nizet, what a tutorial! lets keep this one close and read it some times till i really understand.

Answer (score 1):

The code in your callback

```
function (items){
    $scope.formuleItems = items.data;
}
```

is evaluated asynchronously. That means you first fire the request, then javascript keeps on executing your lines of code, hence performs

```
console.log('+++++++++++++++++', $scope.formuleItems); // gives undefined
```

At this point the callback was not invoked yet, because this takes some time and can happen at any point. The execution is not stopped for this.
Therefore the value of $scope.formuleItems is still undefined, of course.

After that - at some not defined time in the future (probably a few milliseconds later) the callback will be invoked and the value of $scope.formuleItems will be changed. You have to log the value INSIDE of your callback-function.

You urgently have to understand this concept if you want to succeed in JavaScript, because this happens over and over again :)